# Python xlwings: Insert and calculate a non-english Excel-formula into xlsm

Tags: python, excel, formula, xlwings

I want to set an excel formula with the python module xlwings in a xlsm file.

When I set it with the .value function of xlwings the formula gets entered into the file correctly, but on opening the file the formula is not calculated. Instead the cell is displayed as the following Error:

```
"#NAME?"
```

Upon clicking into the cell and pressing the "ENTER"-key it gets calculated correctly. However I obviously do not want to do this for millions of rows / cells in which I entered a formula with Python.

Here is the code I used to insert a value and a formula:

```
import xlwings as xw

workbook = xw.Book('filename.xlsm')
import_sheet = workbook.sheets['my_sheet']
# setting a value
import_sheet['A1'].value = 401  # works as expected.
# setting a function
import_sheet['B1'].value = '=ZEILE()'  # is not displayed correctly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple but not obvious:

Changing the formula to its english counterpart calculates and displays the formula correctly (and even translates it into the language of my excel when I open the file):

```
import_sheet['B1'].value = '=ROW()'
```

My assumption is that it is connected to xlwings language / function processing functionalities? Just a hunch though.